# Как задать группе кнопок атрибут name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, form

```
<form>    
<div class="btn-group" name="gender" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" value="m">M
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" value="f">Ж
     </label>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="save">Продолжить</button>
</form>
```

Почему атрибут `name="gender"` у такой формы не передается на сервер?
Как правильно задать атрибут группе кнопок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это невозможно. У каждого HTML тега есть свой набор атрибутов. Применительно к тегу div атрибут name не предусмотрен стандартом. Тег div имеет другое назначение, нежели элементы форм. Другими словами, тег div является группирующим элементом и не как не относится к элементом формы, значения которых передаются на сервер вместе с HTTP запросом.

Атрибут name применительно к формам и их полям используется для того что бы предоставить возможность программисту в коде серверной части получить доступ к значениям полей формы переданных на сервер в HTTP запросе.

Атрибут name, будет доступен на стороне сервере, только если вы будете его использовать вместе с элементами формы.

Перечень HTML элементов форм, можно посмотреть здесь: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

Answer (score 1):

Потому что атрибут `name` должен быть у `input`, а не у `div`: https://webref.ru/html/input/name